# Spring and Jersey Filter - Provider or Component?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, spring-boot, jax-rs

I'm trying to determine spring-boot, jersey and how the jersey and spring-boot contexts relate to one another.

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }


}
```

When I have it labeled a @Provider and make Jersey look in the package where it lives for it, it doesn't find it. It works when I make it a @Component.

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // DOESNT FIND MY CORSFilter as  Provider
        this.packages("com.mypackage.rest");
    }


}
```

Does the @Configuration annotation make the JerseyContext a spring bean? And then spring injects the CORSFilter because it finds a component of Filter type? What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a servlet filter (implements Filter) which means that the servlet container is instantiating the filter. When you provide the @component annotation, still its the servlet container that initializes this filter. Its only that spring context is aware of this using the contextloader listener.

In jersey your filter should implement the `ContainerRequestFilter` or the `ContainerResponseFilter` so that the jersey configs are applied to the filters like URL path.
Since you used the servlet filter you should configure it manually.